# Flaskにおける複数リクエストの並列処理

Tags: python, flask

Python 3.3.5 + Flaskでサーバアプリを作っています。

### 内容

FlaskにHTTPリクエストを送ると即座にレスポンスを返してくれますが、

- 2つ以上のリクエストを同時に送る

もしくは

- 早かった方のリクエストの処理中に続けてリクエストを送る

といった事をすると、遅かった方のリクエストのレスポンスは早かった方へのレスポンスが完了するまで待たされます。

単一スレッドで処理しているだからだと思われますが、これをFlaskで並列処理できる方法はありませんでしょうか。

### テストに使ったコード

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True)

    @app.route('/')
    def greet():
        n = randrange(1, 10)
        sleep(n)
        return 'Hello world! I slept {0}[s].'.format(str(n))

    app.run()
```

これは、リクエストが飛んできたら乱数を元に1 - 10秒待ち何秒待ったか返すコードです。

ブラウザのタブを2つ用意し、両方素早くlocalhost:5000へアクセスすると、先にアクセスした方にレスポンスが返ってきてから後の方の待つフェーズが始まることが待ち時間からわかります。

もしFlaskが並列でレスポンスを返すことができたら、待ち時間の乱数が小さかったほうが先に返ってくるはずです。

Comment: Gunicornなどで複数プロセスを待機させるのではダメでしょうか

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flask.Flask.runのオプションにprocessesまたはthreadedを指定する事で可能だと思います。
windows環境ではforkがないためproessesはエラーとなりました。

```
    app.run(processes=3)
```

または

```
    app.run(threaded=true)
```

別のブラウザから同時アクセスして同時に処理されることを確認しました。

runのオプションはwerkzeugに渡されるそうなのでoptionsに関してはWerkzeugのドキュメントを参照する必要があります。

> - options – the options to be forwarded to the underlying Werkzeug server. See werkzeug.run_simple() for more information.

[Flask.run (bitbucket.org)](http://a2c.bitbucket.org/flask/api.html?highlight=flask#flask.Flask.run)
[werkzeug parameters (pocoo.org)](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/serving/)

Answer (score 10):

Flask.run() は開発用サーバーであり、実際にサービスを提供するために利用するためのものではありません。
一般的な構成には、

- 静的ファイル配信を nginx で行い、 nginx からリバースプロキシして gunicorn か uWSGI で Flask アプリを動かす。
- Apache と mod_wsgi を使う。

といった選択肢があります。個人的には前者がお勧めです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。nginxの方がおすすめである理由をお聞かせいただければ幸いです。

Comment: mod_wsgi は最近更新がされていません。（安定しているとも言えますが）
また、1つの Apache で複数のアプリを動かすとき、アプリごとに Python のバージョンを選ぶことも難しくなります。

ただし、最近の Apache 2.4 であれば、 unix domain socket へのリバースプロキシやバッファリングなどリバースプロキシ機能が強化されているので、 Apache + gunicorn or uWSGI という構成も可能です。
Apache の方に慣れているのであれば、静的ファイル配信＋リバースプロキシは Apache でも全く問題無いです。

Answer (score 3):

gunicornやwaitress, cherrypyなどのwsgiサーバーを使えばよいでしょう。
とりあえずflaskのサイトにはcherrypyで実行する例がありました。

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/24/

Answer (score 3):

asyncioを使うことでI/Oを多重化する方法があります。

Python3.3上でasyncioを使ったflaskアプリを作成するには、次のことが必要です。

1. asyncioをインストールする

   asyncioは、Python 3.4では標準ライブラリの一つですが、
   Python 3.3では、asyncioを別途インストールすることで使用できます。

   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/asyncio
2. asyncioに対応したflaskを使う

   asyncioを使うように手を入れたflaskがいくつか公開されているようです。
   例えば、以下のものが見つかりました。

   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Async/0.11-dev-20140215

gunicornなどのような、preforkを行うwsgiサーバと組み合わせることも可能です。

なお、テストコードにあるようなsleep文は、

```
yield from asyncio.sleep(n)
```

に書き換えます。