# flaskにおける並列処理

Tags: python, flask

flaskにおいて

```
@app.route(‘/url1/‘)
def func1():
```

———-

```
@app.route(‘/url2/‘)
def func2():
```

とあるときurl1とurl2にほぼ同時にリクエストが来たとして並列処理させるにはどうすれば良いですか？

Comment: [Flaskのデフォルトでは同時アクセスを処理できない](https://qiita.com/5zm/items/251be97d2800bf67b1c6) と [Flaskで多重実行（排他）を制御する方法](https://qiita.com/5zm/items/a6a572c6ee76eed7ed98) を参考に。他に [Flaskにおける複数リクエストの並列処理](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/272/26370) とかも。

Answer (score 1):

Flaskのビルトインサーバー上で動作させている場合は以下で出来るかと。

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5555, threaded=True)
```

uWSGIで動作させている場合は、uWSGIの設定ファイル(uwsgi.ini)で"processes"を2以上に設定すると複数プロセスで並列処理が行われます。

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 2
```